# Scroll-based animation using only CSS

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to animate images when you scroll to them? It's like when you scroll down and get to a certain section of the page, then the images appear. Is it possible using only CSS?

Comment: You can maybe exploit `hover` state [*this way*](https://jsfiddle.net/hq42xopz/). But its not the same as detecting scroll.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```css
/*
 *Styling
 */

html,body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: relative; 
}
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}

header {
    background: #fff; 
    position: fixed; 
    left: 0; top: 0; 
    width:100%;
    height: 3.5rem;
    z-index: 10; 
}

nav {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 0.5rem;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: inherit; 
    margin: 0; 
}


ul li:nth-child( 3n + 1), #main .panel:nth-child( 3n + 1) {
    background: rgb( 0, 180, 255 );
}

ul li:nth-child( 3n + 2), #main .panel:nth-child( 3n + 2) {
    background: rgb( 255, 65, 180 );
}

ul li:nth-child( 3n + 3), #main .panel:nth-child( 3n + 3) {
    background: rgb( 0, 255, 180 );
}

ul li {
    display: inline-block; 
    margin: 0 8px;
    margin: 0 0.5rem;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    padding: 0.3rem 0.5rem;
    border-radius: 2px; 
    line-height: 1.5;
}

ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.panel {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    z-index:0; 
    -webkit-transform: translateZ( 0 );
    transform: translateZ( 0 );
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;

}

.panel h1 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 64px;
    font-size: 4rem;
    color: #fff;
    position:relative;
    line-height: 200px;
    top: 33%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
}

/*
 *Scrolling
 */

a[ id= "servicios" ]:target ~ #main article.panel {
    -webkit-transform: translateY( 0px);
    transform: translateY( 0px );
}

a[ id= "galeria" ]:target ~ #main article.panel {
    -webkit-transform: translateY( -500px );
    transform: translateY( -500px );
}
a[ id= "contacto" ]:target ~ #main article.panel {
    -webkit-transform: translateY( -1000px );
    transform: translateY( -1000px );
}
```

```html
<a id="servicios"></a>
    <a id="galeria"></a>
    <a id="contacto"></a>
    <header class="nav">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#servicios"> Servicios </a> </li>
                <li><a href="#galeria"> Galeria </a> </li>
                <li><a href="#contacto">Contacta  nos </a> </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <section id="main">
        <article class="panel" id="servicios">
            <h1> Nuestros Servicios</h1>
        </article>

        <article class="panel" id="galeria">
            <h1> Mustra de nuestro trabajos</h1>
        </article>

        <article class="panel" id="contacto">
            <h1> Pongamonos en contacto</h1>
        </article>
    </section>
```

or

```css
/* ============================================================
  PRIMARY STRUCTURE
============================================================ */
.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/* ============================================================
  SECTIONS
============================================================ */
section.module:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
section.module h2 {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}
section.module p {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
section.module p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
section.module.content {
  padding: 40px 0;
}
section.module.parallax {
  height: 600px;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
section.module.parallax h1 {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 600px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
section.module.parallax-1 {
  background-image: url("http://labs.qnimate.com/slider/1.jpg");
}
section.module.parallax-2 {
  background-image: url("http://labs.qnimate.com/slider/2.jpg");
}
section.module.parallax-3 {
  background-image: url("http://labs.qnimate.com/slider/3.jpg");
}

@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
  section.module h2 {
    font-size: 42px;
  }
  section.module p {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  section.module.parallax h1 {
    font-size: 96px;
  }
}
@media all and (min-width: 960px) {
  section.module.parallax h1 {
    font-size: 160px;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="module parallax parallax-1">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Serene</h1>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="module content">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="module parallax parallax-2">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Rise</h1>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="module content">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="module parallax parallax-3">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Calm</h1>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="module content">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response Razia. Although it's very informative and I will definitely use your solution in the future, what I need is a code that animates the images when you scroll to them. Say for example, you're scrolling on the page and then you come to the middle part, that's when the animation will happen for the images on that middle part of the page. Is it possible using only CSS or do we have to use JQuery or JS for this? Thanks again. :)

Comment: If you want to apply JS or JQuery  yes you can apply this. You need to modify your code & you will find out lots of tutorials this topic releted in goole.com. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sure It's possible Just use this jQuery plugin .

[OW JS](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/)

Example source [LINK](https://github.com/ashikjs/Responsive-Templete)